# Where is the "Open with..." option in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04

I don't seem to have the "Open with..." option when right clicking things in Ubuntu 11.4, like a .desktop extension for example, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to right click? "Open with" works for me.

Answer (score 1):

*.desktop* files do not have an 'Open With' option

Open **Text Editor** then drag the .desktop file onto the window and it will open it.

or

Use **Terminal** with the gedit command e.g. `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop`